# Data grid view with combo box , add rows from data table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, combobox

Search and display data in data grid view

```
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("Select JV_CODE,JV_ACC_NAME,DEBIT,CREDIT From VOUCHER_DETAIL where VOUCHERNO =:Vno", sgcnn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vno", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = txtJVNo.Text.ToString.Trim

        Dim daVD As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dtVD As New DataTable()

        daVD.Fill(dtVD)
        dgvAccDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dgvAccDetail.DataSource = dtVD


        dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("JV_CODE").ToString.Trim
        dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("JV_ACC_NAME").ToString.Trim
        dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim
        dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("CREDIT").ToString.Trim



    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

There are two rows in `dtVD` data table but result shows only one I stack with this some can tell what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are only assigning the one row.  You have a couple options:

First, this code below here shouldn't really be necessary, of you setup the property binding on the grid.  You'll get better performance that way if you use a bind.  You don't have your GUI code here, but essentially your DataPropertyName field on the columns should be set.

```
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("JV_CODE").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("JV_ACC_NAME").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(0).Item("CREDIT").ToString.Trim
```

If you insist on manually assigning the cell values, you cannot just do row 0 (that's the first row).  You need to do all the rows in a loop.

```
For i as Integer = 0 to dtVD.Rows.Count - 1

    dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("JV_CODE").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("JV_ACC_NAME").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim
    dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("CREDIT").ToString.Trim


Next
```